# Facebook SDK iOS on multiple targets

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am trying to create an app with multiple targets so I can use the code for different apps with small changes. I managed to work with many variables needed by setting custom keys in plist file and making user-defined-settings entries for referencing them. The problem is that with Facebook SDK I cannot do that. I have set a custom key in plist like ${FACEBOOK_APP_ID} and a user defined setting on my target like FACEBOOK_APP_ID with my app's id in it. When I compile and run, I get app_id is required error (of course if I hardcode it on plist works fine). Does anyone know of a solution not requiring to use different plist files for each target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling for days with that without a good solution, I found that if I set preprocess info.plist to Yes, I can add user-defined settings to build-settings as usual and they are available at runtime. Now, I only have to enter the three variables to the target configuration and there is no need for a preprocess file or preprocess macros.

**Update:**

I have added FACEBOOK_DISPLAY_NAME, FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEMES to user defined settings (from Editor->Add Build Setting menu in Xcode) with the proper details for each target. Then In Info.plist (I use one globally for all targets) I added the options Facebook SDK guide states but instead of static values I added ${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}, ${FACEBOOK_URL_SCHEMES}, and ${FACEBOOK_DISPLAY_NAME}. Then on build settings I chose YES to preprocess plist file. Now I can change the info in my user-defined settings for each target and works ok (without the need of an extra preprocess file and the need for defining macros)

Comment: Can you be more specific about this and give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the macro in your difference target, in the code you just define the value by the macro. exampe:
 #if project1
   //the app id const
 #endif

Comment: This will make me go to preprocessor and add the target variable that I am checking with if later. Makes it 2 points to change for each new target. I confirm that this approach works, although I wonder if there is a way to minimize the workload later.

Comment: swift also doesn't allow this method